# Using CoreBluetooth to connect to Windows10 with iOS devices

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bluetooth

Question1.
IOBluetooth can support connection  both ways via LE or classic. However it only supports macOs. CoreBluetooth supports only up to LE along with IOS.

As far as I know, in order for me to connect my bluetooth connection within IOs device, I must use CoreBluetooth frameworks. Am I correct?

Question2.
CoreBluetooth frameworks can connect Windows10 labtop with bluetooth connection?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. I assume you just want to have a way to exchange some data between an iOS app and your Windows 10 desktop.

1. Yes, you are correct. Usage of Bluetooth Classic in any of your iOS apps requires Apple MFI Membership and only makes sense if you have your own product. If you are not a member of the MFI program then you are left with CoreBluetooth (BLE). Please note, that BLE is significantly slower than Bluetooth Classic so it only makes sense for applications that require transmission of small data packets (expect around 4kB/s max).
2. Yes, as long as your Windows 10 device supports BLE. If you want to use any of the SIG adopted Profiles such as HID over Gatt you should be able to connect without any additional software. Otherwise you need to implement your own profile. If you want to know more about your options, I suggest you have a look at the [CoreBluetooth documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth) and/or get a copy of [Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491949511) which is a comprehensive read on the topic.